# TypeScript can't access public property: Property 'PropName' does not exit on 'ClassName'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a TypeScript class with 15 properties.  14 of those are populated by a WebAPI call's response.  The other one is meant to be set at a later time.

For some reason, I am receiving the following error:

> ERROR in ./ClientApp/app/components/home/IncidentTable.component.ts
>   (45,18): error TS2339: Property 'CurrentStatusCssClasses' does not
>   exist on type 'IncidentNode'

**Here is my class:**

```
export class IncidentNode {
    public CurrentStatusCssClasses: string[];
    public RetrievalId: number;
    public IncidentId: number;
    public Name: string;
    public IPAddress: string;
    public MonitorStartTime: string;
    public LastStatusTime: string;
    public IssueTime: string;
    public IssueStatus: string;
    public LastAnalysisTime: string;
    public CurrentStatus: string;
    public LastProblemTime: string;
    public ProblemCount: number;
}
```

**Here is the component (errors occur on lines with `node.CurrentStatusCssClasses.push()`):**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { IncidentNode } from './IncidentNode';

@Component({
    selector: 'incident-node-table',
    template: require('./IncidentTable.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./IncidentTable.component.css')]
})
export class IncidentNodeTableComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() parentSubject: Subject<any>;
    @Input() tableTitle: string;
    IncidentNodes: IncidentNode[] = null;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.parentSubject.subscribe(event => {
            if (event != null) {
                this.IncidentNodes = event;
                this.formatFields();
            }
        });
    }

    formatFields() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.IncidentNodes.length; i++) {
            let node = this.IncidentNodes[i];
            if (node.IssueTime != null) {
                node.IssueTime = this.formatDateInternal(node.IssueTime);
            }
            if (node.LastAnalysisTime != null) {
                node.LastAnalysisTime = this.formatDateInternal(node.LastAnalysisTime);
            }
            if (node.LastProblemTime != null) {
                node.LastProblemTime = this.formatDateInternal(node.LastProblemTime);
            }
            if (node.LastStatusTime != null) {
                node.LastStatusTime = this.formatDateInternal(node.LastStatusTime);
            }
            if (node.MonitorStartTime != null) {
                node.MonitorStartTime = this.formatDateInternal(node.MonitorStartTime);
            }

            node.CurrentStatusCssClasses.push("glyphicon");
            if (node.CurrentStatus == "UpAndActive") {
                node.CurrentStatusCssClasses.push("glyphicon-circle-arrow-down");
            }
            else if (node.CurrentStatus == "NodeOn3GBackup") {
                node.CurrentStatusCssClasses.push("glyphicon-signal");
            } else if (node.CurrentStatus == "UpAndActive") {

            }
        }
    }

    formatDateInternal(dateString: string) {
        let utcDate = moment.utc(dateString);
        let localDate = moment(utcDate).local();
        return localDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird. Is this the exact code you have? Does it complain only about the `CurrentStatusCssClasses` property? If you comment those parts everything else compiles just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Your CurrentStatusCssClasses is an array of strings. However, you need to create that array first (even if it is empty). You could either assign this in your subscribe event handler, or create a constructor of the CurrentStatusCssClasses class and do it there.

```
constructor () {
       this.CurrentStatusCssClasses =  [];
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking about a compilation error. What you suggested would have ended with a runtime error.

Comment: This is correct. Nevertheless you can create a compile time error with the above code as is, depending on your tsconfig settings (eg set strictNullChecks) will create a compile error, although not the one above. There could be a combination of settings, which causes this error, also depending on ts version.

Answer (score -1):

As tom-schier said, CurrentStatusCssClasses does not exist, you need to instantiate it before pushing stuff into it. This is what I would do:

```
CurrentStatusCssClassses: Array<string> = [];
```